# How to create a IntentService to check if GoogleApiClient is not null android

Tags: java, android, google-api-client, intentservice, android-intentservice

In my project I'm using the "GoogleApiClient" to make locations requests each 5 seconds, the problem is, if I turn the GPS off and then reopen the App, it crushes because the `mGoogleApiClient` object is current null! I'm just doing a simple check on `onRestart`

```
protected void onRestart() {
    super.onRestart();
    if(mGoogleApiClient != null && mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()){
        startLocationUpdate();
    }
}
```

What I want is create something that I could call every time the object `mGoogleApiClient` is null so it could try in background until be fine to go on! Inside of  `startLocationUpdate();` I'm using this :

```
mlocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mlocationRequest.setInterval(5000);
    mlocationRequest.setFastestInterval(2000);
    mlocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    try{
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient,mlocationRequest,MainActivity.this);
    }catch (SecurityException ex){
        Toast.makeText(this, ex.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

It could be something like :

```
if(mGoogleApiClient != null){
   LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient,mlocationRequest,MainActivity.this);
  }else {
   callServiceToTryConnection();
}
```

I already use `IntentService` with `Geocoder` to get the address!

Comment: You can try with Android Service and Timer with in service

Answer (score 0):

Check in onRestart that is GPS is enable or not by this condition

```
if ( !manager.isProviderEnabled( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER ) ) {
   //Here is your condition if GPS is not connected
}
```

Comment: I already did, what I want is something to keep trying until the connection return!

Comment: use Handler then it will keep checking after the given time that GPS is available or not

Answer (score 0):

put the handler in on connection suspended or connection failed  method that tries to check and re-connect if not null.

Comment: I can't do it manually!! It has to be a some kinda of timer so each 5 seconds to try again !!

Comment: ya you can set it by using handler class method scheduleatFixedRate in which you have to specify interval after which that task should execute